# How to create custom node.js application starter scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I would like to create custom scripts for creating a new application just like `npx create-react-app my-app`. However, I would like to customize libraries and folder structure etc. However, I am not quite sure how to approach this. I thought about two ways but I am unsure which one will best fit my needs.

1. Should I create a custom package then create the files I need with `fs` etc.
2. A batch script to do the things I mentioned.

I found that express has this feature but it would be nice to be able to customize these settings. Are there any alternative and possibly more efficient methods for doing this?

Also, if I were to do it via nmp packages. How can I run them from the cli?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If customizations are not too advanced, you can start by creating a template repository and place a single `setup` script in it, which can be implemented by using `inquirer` npm module. Here is an example:

[image]

See https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter -> `setup.js`